# Are "If P then Q" and "Q only if P" equivalent?

Tags: logic, deduction

My textbook says "If P then Q" and "Q only if P" are logically equivalent, but consider this:

"If it's green, it's poisonous."

"It's poisonous only if it's green."

Now say there's a purple poisonous frog. The first statement is true and the second statement is false. Thus, they're not equivalent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no clue what ELL is. I dont see how it's an English question, though

Comment: In mathematical logic **P → Q** must be read : "if **P**, then **Q**", as well as : "**P** only if **Q**". Thus "**Q** only if **P**" is **Q → P**, which is **not** equivalent to **P → Q**.

Comment: For reference, you might want to see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311192/how-does-if-p-then-q-have-the-same-meaning-as-q-only-if-p

Comment: A related question on "only if" http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/how-can-we-reason-about-if-p-then-q-or-p-only-if-q-statements-in-proposition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we reason about "if P then Q" or "P only if Q" statements in propositional logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/how-can-we-reason-about-if-p-then-q-or-p-only-if-q-statements-in-proposition)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In mathematical logic **P → Q** must be read :

"if **P**, then **Q**", as well as : "**P** only if **Q**".

Thus "**Q** only if **P**" is **Q → P**, which is **not** equivalent to **P → Q**.

---

You can see also this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617562/conditional-statements-only-if) as well as this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311192/how-does-if-p-then-q-have-the-same-meaning-as-q-only-if-p).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of looking at this.

The statement **X if and only if Y** expresses the logical equivalence of **X** and **Y** and is written **X ⇔ Y**.

This is the conjuction of the two conditionals **X ⇒ Y** and **Y ⇒ X**.

The "if" conjunct corresponds to **Y ⇒ X** and the "only if" conjuct corresponds to **X ⇒ Y**.

It should be obvious then, that the statement "if P then Q" is not equivalent to "Q only if P".

Answer (score 1):

If you use an example that’s biconditional it won’t be a good example because it’s not going to help you understand why it works. Try using examples that are true if then statements.

“If p then q” says “if p is true then q is true”, so p is true only if q is true. If q is false than p can’t be true, so p is true only if q is true.
If a frog is green then it is poisonous was the example given but it’s also true that if a frog is green then it is not poisonous so the example is misleading and confusing; the premise is false/fallacious in the first place.

If a man is a bachelor than he is single,  is the same as saying a man is a bachelor only if he is single.

Also “if p then q” is the same as “p only if q” not “q only if p”.

Answer (score 0):

There are implications in your 1st statement that make it false! The only way to make it true, would be if **all** and **only** green frogs are poisonous. Then the second statement, poisonous only if green, would be true.  An example of this would be if you put green poisonous frogs in a room, together with **non-poisonous** purple, orange, yellow, etc. frogs.  Under these conditions, both statements: if green, then poisonous and poisonous only if green, would be true!

Answer (score 0):

No; they are not. Please see my intuitive explanation [located at Math SE here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1593526/53259), which I cannot reproduce here because Philosophy SE lacks MathJax formatting, as at Dec 2015.

Answer (score -1):

Since your question is "what am I doing wrong", you are making one of two possible mistakes:

One is that you are committing an "appeal to authority" fallacy. You believe the statement because you found it in your textbook. However, the statement is false: "If P then Q" and "Q only if P" are *not* equivalent.

The other and frankly more likely mistake is that you have misread what your textbook says. Maybe there was a section in the textbook titled "show which of the following statements are true and which are false".

A simple example where the statements are not equivalent: "If a person is a man, then that person is a human being" vs. "A person is only a human being if that person is a man".